# django unable to render form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm new to django.
look at the following code in my form.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label=_("first name"))
    lname = forms.CharField(label=_("last name"))
    phone= forms.CharField(label=_("phone"))
    address = forms.CharField(label=_("address"))

    def categorize_fields(self):
        categorized_fields = [
        [ self.fields["name"], self.fields["lname"]  ] ,
        [ self.fields["phone"], self.fields["address"]  ]
        ]
        return categorized_fields
```

in my form render I have the following code which does not work properly:

```
  {% for field_set in form.categorize_fields %}
         {% for field in field_set %}
             {{ field.label }}
             {{ field }}
         {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

`field.label` is working correctly but `{{ field }}` is not showing the HTML rendered and instead is showing this:

```
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x000012661591CA90>
```

but if I iterate through the main form passed to form_render.html, everything works fine:

```
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
```

how can I solve that?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.fields` contains references to the unbound field objects. If you want access to the actual bound fields, you need to index on `self` directly:

```
categorized_fields = [
    [ self["name"], self["lname"]  ] ,
    [ self["phone"], self["address"]  ]
]
```

However, I do not recommend doing this. Instead, use a third-party library like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).